# Immutable method to change attribute in an array of objects

Tags: ruby

I have a following array

```
Bot = Struct.new(:name, :age)

bots = %w(foo bar baz).map do |name|
  Bot.new(name, rand(10))
end

p bots
[ #<struct Bot name="foo", age=3>, 
  #<struct Bot name="bar", age=8>, 
  #<struct Bot name="baz", age=0> ]
```

I want to get a new array from `bots`, where `age` attribute converted `to_s`, but I don't want to change the real objects in the array `bots`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will preserve bots:

```
new_bots = bots.map {|bot| Bot.new(bot.name, bot.age.to_s) }
```

This will **not** preserve bots:

```
new_bots = bots.map! {|bot| Bot.new(bot.name, bot.age.to_s) }
```

map! modifies the object it is called on, as do most methods that end in !.  It is the mutable version of map.

map does not modify the contents of the object it is called on.  Most array methods are immutable, except those that end in ! (but is only a convention, so be careful).

Answer (score 1):

```
Bot = Struct.new(:name, :age)

bots = %w(foo bar baz).map do |name|
  Bot.new(name, rand(10))
end
#=> [#<struct Bot name="foo", age=4>,
#    #<struct Bot name="bar", age=5>,
#    #<struct Bot name="baz", age=8>]

bots.map { |bot| Bot.new(bot.name, bot.age.to_s)}
#=> [#<struct Bot name="foo", age="4">,
#    #<struct Bot name="bar", age="5">,
#    #<struct Bot name="baz", age="8">]
```